# Invalid JSON payload received when appending to Google Sheets API V4

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Hi I've a small tool to edit a Google Sheet using the API v4. I can read the data from said sheet but I can't append anything.

```
               $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' +
                        'SPREADSHEETID' +
                        '/values/' + 'TAB' +
                        '?alt=json&key=KEY',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        majorDimension: 'ROWS',
                        range: 'A1:A2',
                        values: '32'
                    },
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
```

This is the code I'm using, but I keep getting the following error: `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"values\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'values' could not be found in request message."`

Comment: check your format: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/588#issuecomment-243323554

Comment: is it the same for ajax, I'm not using nodejs. @Kos

Comment: What is `TAB`??

Comment: @TheMaster When I saw the endpoint of the script, I thought that OP might want to use the method of spreadsheets.values.update of Sheets API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) In that case, I think that `TAB` will be the range. And, that might be the sheet name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the values to the Spreadsheet using the method of spreadsheets.values.update of Sheets API with ajax.

#### Modification points:

- The method of spreadsheets.values.update uses the PUT method. In your script, it seems that you are trying to use the POST method.
- Unfortunately, in the current stage, when the PUT and POST methods are used, these methods cannot be requested with the API key. In this case, please use the access token.
- In the method of spreadsheets.values.update, please send the request body as the string type. And, the content type is `application/json`.
- And, the value is a 2-dimensional array.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/###spreadsheetId###/values/A1?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED',
  method: 'PUT',
  data: JSON.stringify({majorDimension: 'ROWS', values: [['32']]}),
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer ###your access token###",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function (res) {
    console.log(res.responseText);
  }
});
```

- When you use `A1` as the range, the value is put to the 1st tab. When you want to put the value to the specific sheet, for example, please use `Sheet2!A1`. Please be careful about this.
- By the way, from `appending to Google Sheets` of `Invalid JSON payload received when appending to Google Sheets API V4`, if you want to append the value of `"32"` to the Spreadsheet, please modify the above script as follows. The reference of the method of spreadsheets.values.append is [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append).

  - From

    ```
      url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/###spreadsheetId###/values/A1?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED',
      method: 'PUT',
    ```
  - To

    ```
      url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/###spreadsheetId###/values/###SheetName###:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED',
      method: 'POST',
    ```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: How do I get the bearer token?

Comment: @Guillermo Oramas R. Thank you for replying. About your new question of `How do I get the bearer token?`, in this case, I think that you can retrieve the access token from [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) and/or [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)?

Comment: @Tanike perfect, thank you very much, I will try it.

Comment: @Guillermo Oramas R. Thank you for replying.